# REST API login through headers (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I am trying to communicate two apps of my own, one has a REST api and the other consumes it.

My login page is on the second app, so I would like to transfer credentials on every request to the other layer. I thought about including username & password in the request headers.

Provided I got ahold of username & password on the REST layer, how would I use this information on the REST layer to "authenticate the request" prior to processing the requestmapping and thus be able to use Spring Security annotations afterwards whithin this layer?

I need user info on the REST layer for ACL as well.

Comment: Use HTTP Basic authentication maybe? Spring Security has good support for it.

Comment: Can that be done against a database? Can I then get user details & roles from the repository? Have you got any good links on the matter?

Comment: Sure, you can authenticate against a database. The reference manual is a good starting point: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/ Look for UserDetailsService.

Comment: @Orion it's authorization on the resource level, that is, the security policy applied for instance on Facebook so you can only see *your* pictures.